# How to have two user level in one db php

Tags: php, sql

I have 2 user level, one is for the admin_tbl and the other is for cashier_tbl they have the same database. My problem is whether I log out either cashier or admin the other one is also log out when I refresh the page. I dont know what the problem is, I used different table so but it log out both of them at the same time? kindly help me with this problem, give me some ideas of whats wrong. Thanks!

UPDATE: Thats my logout code for both cashier_tbl and admin_tbl

This is my code for cashier_tbl

```
 <?php



session_start();



$_SESSION = array();



if (ini_get("session.use_cookies")){

        $params = session_get_cookie_params();

        setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000,

            $params["path"], $params["domain"],

            $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]

    );

}



session_destroy();

header("Location: index.php");

?>
```

And this is for my admin_tbl

```
    <?php

session_start();

$_SESSION = array();

if (ini_get("session.use_cookies")){
        $params = session_get_cookie_params();
        setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000,
            $params["path"], $params["domain"],
            $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]
    );
}

session_destroy();
header("Location: index.php");
?>
```

Comment: You should look into sql injection. And you should never store plain-text passwords.

Comment: how can both of those be index.php?

Comment: @jeroen  uName = getRequestString("username");
uPass = getRequestString("password");

sql = "SELECT * FROM admin_tbl WHERE uname="' + uName + '" AND pword="' + uPass + '""; Is it correct?

Comment: I think you may need to use unset ($_SESSION['user_id']) instead of session_unset to clear your session vars

Comment: @delboy1978uk Because both of them is log in page.

Comment: tbh i think your db design is flawed, all users should go in one table, and then you should have cashier and admin tables both pointing to the users id in the user table

Comment: @delboy1978uk So what should I do man?

Comment: Not directly related, but 1) your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL.

Comment: 2) `header("Location: user_maintenance.php");` and all other similar redirect calls must be followed by `die();`, otherwise the PHP script will continue and output all the content anyway, even if it was meant to be hidden for security reasons. A browser will honour the redirect and ignore it, but the data is still being leaked, and other clients such as webcrawlers and bots will not stop when they get the redirect header, and will just read all the content anyway. So any kind of security redirect which doesn't then kill the script execution is not secure at all.

Comment: 3) You appear not to be hashing passwords. This is not very secure for your users. Look into how you do this, there are tools available already in PHP/MySQL.

Comment: 4) Your data structure is crazy, as others have mentioned. One users table (and one login script shared between the different pages, rather than duplicating near-identical code) should be the solution. You can determine the type of user by values in a specific column in your users table. Perhaps you need to study the basic concepts of entity-relations and database normalisation.

Comment: 5) You seem to be using the same SESSION variable for both types of user. Example: If you log in as a cashier it sets the user_id variable in the session. Next time you try to access a page that's intended for admins, it checks the same user_id variable in the session, it sees that it's populated and allows the user to continue. It doesn't know what type of user it is, only the ID. You need to store the user type in the session, and check that as well. Then only allow users with the right type to access pages intended for that type.

Comment: 6) session_unset() has no effect because you call it before session_start(), so there's no session on which to unset anything. Not sure you really need this function anyway, if you do what I suggested in point 5 above. If you have some logout code somewhere, that should be unsetting the specific user_id variables. Alternatively you can stick to one user_id variable, and force the user to log out before they can log in as a different user type again. For logging out use session_destroy() rather than session_unset(), which is weaker. Lots of online material about this kind of thing

Comment: Obviously the above depends on whether you want allow logins to multiple user types simultaneously or not, or whether one user account can be in both user type roles simultaneously or not.

Comment: @ADyson Thanks bro! it helps. I change the user_id of my cashier in user_id2 and its not both login anymore when I login either one of them. But  my problem now is whenever I logout the out is also logout. I hope you guys can help me with this to.

Comment: well we can't see your logout code, but I guess you need to just unset the specific user_id or user_id2 variable, rather than destroy the whole session.

Comment: @Adyson Oww sorry, I'll edit my post, I'll put my logout code.

Comment: why did you remove the rest of your code apart from the logout bits (which seem to be identical)? It's still relevant. Anyway yeah like I said, if you want to log out only one of the user types, don't use session_destroy and don't set the whole of $_SESSION to an empty array, instead just unset the specific session variable for that user type.

Comment: @Adyson Instead of $_SESSION = array(); it is $_SESSION = user_id2();? it is correct bro? :3

Comment: No. That would assign the whole $_SESSION value to be that one value. That's simple variable assignment syntax, you should know that? You need to _unset_ the specific item in the session array. As in, using the `unset()` function.

Comment: @ADyson I dont quiet understand man, I think this one?
 unset($_SESSION['user_id2']);

Comment: that should be it, yes. And anything else, if you stored the name or anything like that.

Comment: @ADyson its good bro. It WORKED! Thanks to you bro!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem on this line :

```
if (isset($_SESSION['user_id']))
 {
    header("Location: user_maintenance.php");
    }
```

it's redirect you to user_maintenance.php even if $_SESSION is empty. And on :

```
if (isset($_SESSION['user_id']))
 {
    header("Location: order.php");
    }
```

is same to.

These is the others correct way.

I assumed you never set `session_unset()` or `session_destroy()` in your logout method.

Delete `session_unset()` and `session_start();` in the first line of your code above, it's not neccessary.

After check the user login method like your code above, in your file order.php and user_maintenance.php, start the session. it would something like this :

```
<?php
 session_start();

 // check if the user was login or not
 if($_SESSION['login'] == false){
  header('Location: user-is-not-login.php');
 }
?>

// this area can be access if session is true.
```

create logout method in location that session was set. something like this :

```
<?php
 session_start();

 session_destroy();
 session_unset();

 header('Location: login.php');
?>
```

You need to destroy the session before set a new session.

hope these help.

Comment: Yep dude, I have logout for both of them, but my problem now is whenever I logout either one of them the other one is also logout. And I have session_destroy(); in my logout bro.